# Outer join with group by subqueries

Tags: sql, database, oracle, outer-join

I'm trying to execute a query in an Oracle 10g DB to join two subqueries as it follows:

```
SELECT * FROM(
select count(y), x from a group by y) t1 
full join 
(select count(z), x from b group by z) t2 
on (t1.x = t2.x)
```

The problem is that the output shows two different columns for x as it follows:

```
  y           z           x           x1        
-------------------------------------------
  2           4           1           1           
  3           (null)      2           (null)      
  2           (null)      3           (null)      
  8           (null)      4           (null)      
  (null)      4           (null)      5           
  (null)      6           (null)      6
```

Does anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show what results you expect/desire.  I'm guessing you want a UNION, but I can't be sure until I know what results you actually need.

Comment: I want to join the tables using the x attribute, is not a union because they have only one common column. Using coalesce I solve the problem, but I don't know why the full join on x attribute doesn´t generate one column instead of two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you want is:

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.x, t2.x) x, t1.y, t2.z
FROM (select count(y), x from a group by x) t1 
full join (select count(z), x from b group by x) t2 on (t1.x = t2.x)
```